# MySQL: Created Table won't show values?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I created a table called students with some attributes but when I run `Select * From Students` it appears as null for each category I'm not sure why

```
use  practice;

create table Students(
    sid     integer  default 1,
    sname   varchar(50)  default 'Joe',
    GPA     real         default 1.7,
    dateOfBirth date     default (2000-12-12),
    primary key(sid)
);

select *
from Students
```

Comment: you dont have data in your table right? default attributes get added when you insert a row without specifying a value for an attribute

Comment: Your query tries to show the data from the table. But you have inserted nothing, hence no data to show, and you receive empty dataset. Insert some rows with INSERT INTO query then select inserted data.

Comment: okay will try that

Comment: Okay it worked thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to insert a value in your table `(Insert into Students ('sid', 'sname', 'GPA', 'dateOfBirth') Values ('NULL', 'joe', '1.7', '200-12-12');` this will solve your problem with the `SELECT *` 
I would also add an auto increment on your sid so you can putt the value of sid to null and it will automatically `ALTER TABLE Students MODIFY 'sid' INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;`